# Reference for unique classical solution to quasilinear uniformly parabolic PDEs

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, parabolic-pde, fixed-point-theorems

In [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416865/banachs-fixed-point-theorem-for-quasilinear-parabolic-pdes), the author mentioned that "we know there is a unique classical solution (see the references below, for example)". I have tried to read the two references the author provided, but couldn't precisely locate the result the author is referring to. Does anyone know a precise reference to this seemingly classical result?